# string::replace throws std::out_of_range on valid iterators

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost, iterator

Really can't figure out the reason for 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range''

```
std::cerr << std::string(s[0].first, s[0].second) << std::endl;
std::cerr << std::string(e[0].first, e[0].second) << std::endl;
std::cerr << std::string(s[0].first, e[0].second) << std::endl;
```

the above code return valid strings with matched results

```
    boost::regex start(elementStartTag);
    boost::regex end(elementEndTag);

    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> s, e;

    if(!boost::regex_search(tmpTemplate, s, start)) {
        dDebug() << "No start token: " << elementStartTag << " was found in file: " << templatePath();
        std::cerr << "No start token: " << elementStartTag << " was found in file: " << templatePath() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if(!boost::regex_search(tmpTemplate, e, end)) {
        dDebug() << "No end token: " << elementEndTag << " was found in file: " << templatePath();
        std::cerr << "No end token: " << elementEndTag << " was found in file: " << templatePath() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    //std::string::iterator si, ei;
    //        si = fromConst(tmpTemplate.begin(), s[0].second);
    //        ei = fromConst(tmpTemplate.begin(), e[0].first);

    //        std::cerr << std::string(si, ei) << "\t" << ss.str(); // return valid string

    std::cerr << std::string(s[0].first, s[0].second) << std::endl;
    std::cerr << std::string(e[0].first, e[0].second) << std::endl;
    std::cerr << std::string(s[0].first, e[0].second) << std::endl;


    std::cerr << "s[0].first - tmpTemplate.begin()\t" << s[0].first - tmpTemplate.begin() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "s[0].first - e[0].second\t" << s[0].first - e[0].second << std::endl;

    //tmpTemplate.replace(fi, se, ss.str()); //also throws exeption
    tmpTemplate.replace(s[0].first - tmpTemplate.begin(), s[0].first - e[0].second, "test"); // throws exeption
```

gcc version: 4.7.3 if it really matters

boost version: 1.52.0

UPDATE:

First: 
The following equation is wrong s[0].first - e[0].second should be e[0].second - s[0].first - i wonder why nobody saw this (me also) - but consider it a typo, cause s[0].first - tmpTemplate.begin() return negative number anyway.

tmpTemplate defined and initialized as

```
  std::string tmpTemplate= getTemplate();
```

Great - as i said s[0].first - tmpTemplate.begin() returns negative number

if tmpTemplate is defined and initialized as

```
std::string tmpTemplate(getTemplate().data(), getTemplate().length());
```

everything is fine.

Second:

stop boost::match_results uninitialized nonsense please read the regex_search documentation it says: "If i find no match i return false"

Third:

```
std::string tmpTemplate= getTemplate();
```

and

```
std::string tmpTemplate(getTemplate().data(), getTemplate().length());
```

DOES REALLY DIFFER.

Own Сonclusion:

It is ether a memory corruption which occurs else where in my code and i can't detect it with valgrind, or a bug which is not part of my code.

Comment: `can't figure out the reason ` you dont check whether the match_results objects are empty or not. Why are you so surprised?

Comment: wat? std::cerr << std::string(s[0].first, e[0].second) << std::endl; returns my imagination and not the matched string then perhaps? Moreover: "Postconditions: If the function returns false, then the effect on parameter m is undefined, otherwise the effects on parameter m are given in the table:" quote from regex_search documentation.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Thank me later.

Comment: Good guys can stop jerk and give meaningless comments. This is a bug.

Comment: No it isn't. Provide a self contained sample that shows the "bug". Then we'll talk (http://sscce.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

What are the contents of `tmpTemplate`, `elementStartTag` and `elementEndTag`?  If the `elementEndTag` precedes the `elementStartTag` in `tmpTemplate`, then you'll definitely get an `out_of_range` error.

In the end, I'd recommend using just one regular expression, along the lines of:

```
boost::regex matcher( ".*(" + elementStartTag + ")(.*)(" + elementEndTag + ").*");
```

and then using `boost::regex_match` rather than search.  This guarantees the order; it may cause problems if there is more than one matching element in the sequence, however.  If this is an issue: you should use:

```
boost::regex_search( s[1].second, tmpTemplate.end(), e, end )
```

as the expression for matching the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for some usefull response still the problem was solved with replacing by replacing initilizer of std::string tmpTemplate = getTemplate(); to std::string tmpTemplate(getTemplate().data(), getTemplate().length()); the reason wans't s[0].first > e[0].second.

Comment: @Maquefel There's more to it that that.  That change shouldn't change anything.

Comment: nope exactly this one - as i pointed in my question the first 3 lines works perfectly first one outputs desired elementStartTag,  second desired elementEndTag the third outputs from begin of elementStartTag to the end of elementEndTag. What makes you people think that problem is with returned iterators? What is unclear with 'the above code return valid strings with matched results' phrase ?

Comment: @Maquefel There's something else.  _If_ `tmpTemplate` is an `std::string`, and that's the only variable you use for the string, then it makes no difference how it was constructed.

Comment: it differs - should i really explain why?